# select particular element in row of table view in titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

hi I am developing Android application using Titanium. I want to change image on click event.But I am unable to select particular image in table view.I used following code:

```
var user_table = Ti.UI.createTableView({minRowHeight:5.length,hasChild:true});
var data = [];
for (var i=0;i<5.length;i++)
    {
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto',className:"row"});
        var username = Ti.UI.createLabel(
        {
            text:'user name',
            height:'auto',
            font:{fontSize:12, fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue', color:'#000'},
            width:'auto',
            color:'#000',
            textAlign:'left',
            top:0,
            left:35,
        });row.add(username);
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView(
        {
            image:'../images/user.png',
            left:0,
            top:0,
            height:25,
            width:25
        });row.add(imageView);          
    }
    feed_table.setData(data);
    feedWin.add(feed_table);
```

I want to target image in particular row of table view so that i can replace it with another image on click event. help me for selecting that particular image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) in your table view, set the event listener on the whole row.

```
tableView.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    if ( event.source.id === undefined ) {
        // if no id defined then you know it is not an image...
    } else {
        // you have an id, you have an image..
        var rowNumber = event.index;
        var image = event.source;
    }
});
```

2) when you create your images, set an id on each one so you can identify it in the click event

```
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    id :"image_"+ i, // set object id
    image:'../images/user.png',
    left:0,
    top:0,
    height:25,
    width:25
 });
```

Comment: Hi Aaron thanks for the reply.I tried above code but it gives me error **"event"** is not defined.

Comment: sorry, the code is not perfect, but you should be able to do simple debugging and analysis of an undefined variable in approximately 30 lines of code?  Change has been made

Answer (score -1):

i would do it this way:

```
addRow = function(_args)
{
  var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow(
  {
    height:'auto',
    className:"row"
  });

  var username = Ti.UI.createLabel(
  {
    text: _args.text || 'user name',
    height:'auto',
    font:{fontSize:12, fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue', color:'#000'},
    width:'auto',
    color:'#000',
    textAlign:'left',
    top:0,
    left:35,
  });
  row.add(username);

  var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView(
  {
    image:_args.image||'../images/user.png',
    left:0,
    top:0,
    height:25,
    width:25
  });
  row.add(imageView);    

  row.setImage = function(image)
  {
    imageView.imageURL = image;
  };

  row.addEventListener('click',function(e)
  {
    row.setImage('new/image/path');
  };

  return row;
}

var user_table = Ti.UI.createTableView({minRowHeight:5.length,hasChild:true});
var data = [];
for (var i=0;i<5.length;i++)
{
  var newRow = addRow({
    text: 'my text',
    image: 'my image url'
  });
  data.push(newRow);
}

feed_table.setData(data);
feedWin.add(feed_table);
```

if you need to set the url you should also use

```
feedWin.data[0].rows[indexOfRow].setImage('another/image/path');
```

give it a try. didn't compile that, so it's just a proposal.

**[update]** be aware that 'auto' values may suck at android.

Comment: I've down voted for a couple reasons: There's a good amount of complexity you can avoid here. Adding event listeners to every row isn't necessary, and introduces extra weight. As Aaron's example demonstrates, you can instead add a listener to the entire table and look at which elements are clicked (event.source) to control what happens when an element is clicked. I'd also recommend you not store functions on each row. If you had a couple thousand rows, this would mean a couple thousand unique functions, when you really only need one. Make sense?